# Should I array or collection or what

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, dynamic-arrays

my first post, so I hope I am keeping in the rules.  I am converting to C# programming and I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction on this point.
I have a stream of data consisting of integer pairs which I want to store. There could be between 15,000 and 250,000 pairs. Once they are collected I just need to read through the whole group - always all of them and the order is unimportant.

I have just got confused with all the options.
in VBA I would use a collection of variant arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a `List<Tuple<int,int>>` to store your data, personally I would recommend a custom type though that gives *meaning* to each property (instead them just being Item1 and Item2).

Using a list would be preferable to an array unless you know the exact number of items to store in advance.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer has cut through the options and got me a great answer. Cheers.